# jhipster openapi-client , failed to genereate client code

Tags: jhipster, openapi

i'd like to generate code basing on openapi yaml file from jhipster, refering https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/  i have done this:

```
D:\dev\jhipster-app\openapi-demo>jhipster openapi-client
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! Executing jhipster:openapi-client
Welcome to the JHipster OpenApi client Sub-Generator
? Where do you want to import your OpenAPI/Swagger specification from ? From a custom specification file or endpoint
? Where is your Swagger/OpenAPI spec (URL or path) ? http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
? What is the unique name for your API client (please avoid using Java keywords) ? petstore
? Do you want to save this config for future reuse ? No
```

and it prompts the error:

```
Unable to find package.json. Reference to npm script (name: openapi-client:petstore, data:openapi-generator generate -g spring -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -p library=spring-cloud -p apiPackage=undefined.client.petstore.api -p modelPackage=undefined.client.petstore.model -p basePackage=undefined.client -p configPackage=undefined.client.petstore -p title=petstore -p artifactId=petstore -p supportingFiles=ApiKeyRequestInterceptor.java --skip-validate-spec) not added.

ERROR! Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at module.exports.getMicroserviceAppName (D:\users\dev\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:1252:66)
```

Would someone have any idea to fix it?

Comment: This error means that the generator could not find the name of your microservice as you may have seen by reading the code where the error occurs. Now the root cause depends probably on your project or environment, so the best would be to debu the generator in your poject.

Answer (score 0):

I download the sample pestore.yaml from swagger and put it to an existing project 's "src/main/resources/swagger/" folder with renaming to api.yml.

and run jhipster openapi-client:

```
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
INFO! No custom sharedOptions found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-vuejs at /mnt/program/dev/github/jhipster-app/vuedemo/node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs
INFO! No custom commands found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-vuejs at /mnt/program/dev/github/jhipster-app/vuedemo/node_modules/generator-jhipster-vuejs
INFO! Executing jhipster:openapi-client
Welcome to the JHipster OpenApi client Sub-Generator
? What do you want to do ? Generate a new API client
? Where do you want to import your OpenAPI/Swagger specification from ? From the api.yml spec of an existing Jhipster project
? Enter the path to the jhipster project root directory /program/github/jhipster-app/vuedemo
? What is the unique name for your API client (please avoid using Java keywords) ? petstore
? Do you want to save this config for future reuse ? No
```

the result seems ok:

```
Generating npm script for generating client code petstore (/program/github/jhipster-app/vuedemo/src/main/resources/swagger/api.yml)
identical .openapi-generator-ignore
identical pom.xml
identical src/main/java/com/demo/VuedemoApp.java
identical package.json
    force .yo-rc.json

Generating client for petstore

> vuedemo@0.0.0 openapi-client:petstore /mnt/program/dev/github/jhipster-app/vuedemo
> openapi-generator generate -g spring -i /program/github/jhipster-app/vuedemo/src/main/resources/swagger/api.yml -p library=spring-cloud -p apiPackage=com.demo.client.petstore.api -p modelPackage=com.demo.client.petstore.model -p basePackage=com.demo.client -p configPackage=com.demo.client.petstore -p title=petstore -p artifactId=petstore -p supportingFiles=ApiKeyRequestInterceptor.java --skip-validate-spec

Usage: openapi-generator [options] [command]

Options:
  -V, --version                      output the version number
  -d, --sdkDir <sdkDir>              sdkDir, default: process.cwd()/service
  -t, --templatePath <templatePath>  templatePath
  -t, --type <type>                  ts/js, default ts
  -c, --camelCase <camelCase>        filename style, true 为大驼峰，lower 为小驼峰
  -d, --sdkDir <sdkDir>              sdkDir, default: process.cwd()/service
  -t, --templatePath <templatePath>  templatePath
  -t, --type <type>                  ts/js, default ts
  -c, --camelCase <camelCase>        filename style, true 为大驼峰，lower 为小驼峰
  -h, --help                         output usage information

Commands:
  url <url>                          swagger2/oas3 json data url
  data <filePath>                    swagger2/oas3 json data file
  config <cfgPath>                   config path
  *
✔ Succesfully generated petstore spring client
End of openapi-client generator
INFO! Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
```

but I can't find any code generated in src/main/webapp

Comment: my openapi-generator version is 0.1.37. Is it the correct one jhipster required?

Answer (score 0):

jhipster openapi-client generate java code for the server, not typescript code for the client :(